# Avoiding Backbone Router redirect to non-hashbang

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, single-page-application

I realize that backbone is super old at this point :/

However, I'm working on an old app and we've revived the backbone router. The router works locally as I would expect. We have URLs like:

```
/admin/#/users
```

I'm using a domain (non-localhost) and Chrome locally for development. When you load that route in development, it loads the right router in Backbone and the URLs stay like that.

When I deploy the app to a staging ENV (AWS based URLs), the URLs get rewritten like:

```
/admin/#/users -> /admin/users
```

I'm trying to avoid this happening. I want to keep the hashbang URLs. I've tried all combos of settings with `pushState` and `hashChange` and none have any effect on the behavior. I've been putting breakpoints in Chrome's developer tools and still can't figure out why this would be happening.

We're using Backbone v. 1.0.0, so it's a little out of date, which is important to note, b/c I've compared the router code to master and it's a little different.

Any thoughts on why URLs would change in a different environment?

Comment: Is this an existing AWS instance?  I am assuming there is some old configuration getting in the way.  Is it hosted on S3?

Comment: Turns out it was crappy code in Google Tag Manager :/ Ah, the frustration...Thanks for chiming in!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out is was Google Tag Manager and some code that had been pasted in there modifying URLs in the staging ENV. Backbone was doing the right thing and not modifying URLs with `pushState` set to `false`.